# threejs - raycasting reports wrong faceIndex when picking a face

Tags: three.js

threejs - raycasting reports wrong faceIndex when picking a face

I want to pick a face in a mesh when clicking on it with the mouse.
The mesh is loaded using ObjLoader and MtlLoader (attached)
When hovering on the mesh, the intersection is detected correctly, but the reported faceIndex does not match the face index in the .obj file 
(as well as the vertices of the reported face)

For example,

face 0 (f 3/1 1/1 10/1) - has vertices 3,1,10
when hovering on it in the object file, console.log(intersects[0]); reports: "faceIndex: 0" and "face: Ya {a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, ...}"

face 1 (f 3/1 10/1 7/1) - has vertices 3,10,7
when hovering on it in the object file, console.log(intersects[0]); reports: "faceIndex: 3" and "face: Ya {a: 3, b: 4, c: 5, ...}"

face 3 (f 2/2 4/3 8/4) - has vertices 2,4,8
when hovering on it in the object file, console.log(intersects[0]); reports: "faceIndex: 9" and "face: Ya {a: 9, b: 10, c: 11, ...}"

Attached [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dazkw6a6hcfbxib/example2_objLoader_raycasting.zip?dl=0) is a small self-contained example that is based on webgl_interactive_cubes.html and the .obj file.

It looks like the faceIndex is the face index (location) in the .obj file multiplied by 3.
Can anyone tell what is the rational for this, and is this the correct way to map the reported faceIndex to a face in the .obj file?

Thanks,
Avner

Comment: I think OBJ loader creates a triangle soup, meaning your indecis just go away? Would this make sense with your numbers? You should set up a fiddle instead of a zip.

Comment: Also, vertex indexing in OBJ format is 1 based not 0 based which is super confusing.